# ¿Por qué obtengo esta advertencia del compilador al comparar posición de un array de texto con un carácter de espacio?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
char frase[] = "Hola que tal.";
char contadorCaracteres = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
    if (frase[i] != " ") {
        contadorCaracteres++
    }
}
```

El programa solo me tiene que contar los caracteres de la variable `frase`, sin contar los espacios en blanco. Sin embargo, me salta este error:

> warning: comparison between pointer and integer    if(frase[i]!=" ") {

¿Cómo lo soluciono? ¿Por qué pasa?

Gracias.

Comment: Deberia ser: `frase[i] != ' '`

Comment: Cierto, estoy aprendiendo C desde cero y no lo entiendo mucho, me puedes explicar porque funciona cómo lo dices tu?

Comment: Es que si esta entre `" "` es un array de caracteres. Mientras que si esta entre `' '` es un caracter unicamente @Marc

Comment: @Pablochaches Entiendo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo que pasa es que comparas un literal de cadena (comillas dobles) con un `char` (comillas simples). Explicando la advertencia que te tira, te dice *pointer* refiriéndose a un string e *integer* refiriendo a un carácter (un entero de 8 bits). En otras palabras lo que el compilador dice es: *"Cuidado, estás comparando un string con un carácter"*.

Comment: @Marc Dejé una respuesta, espero te sirva, saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > ¿Por qué obtengo esta advertencia del compilador al comparar posición de un array de texto con un carácter de espacio?

Veamos esta línea de código:

```c
if (frase[i] != " ")
```

La variable `frase[i]` es de tipo `char` (aunque en realidad guarda un *entero*) y el literal `" "` es de tipo `char*`. Entonces, el compilador lanza esa advertencia porque hay una **incompatibilidad de tipos** (no pueden trabajar juntos).

> > ¿Por qué la condición siempre se cumple?

Como verás, una cadena literal no es mas que un bloque de memoria y cuando el compilador ve el literal, lo reemplaza por un número y justamente ese **número** es la **dirección de memoria** del primer elemento de dicha cadena.

El código de arriba es equivalente a esto:

```c
char* p = " "; 
if (frase[i] != p)
```

Lo que guarda el puntero `p` es la dirección del primer elemento de la cadena. La cadena literal se ve reflejada así en memoria:

```c
//Claro, toda cadena termina con un caracter nulo para indicar el fin de la cadena.
0x05  0x06
 32    \0
```

En la dirección `0x05` es donde se guarda el caracter (es decir, el espacio), aunque en realidad, lo que se almacena es el código ASCII del caracter (en este caso es `32`). Por ende, el puntero `p` en este ejemplo, tendría guardada la dirección `0x05`.

Por lo tanto, esa condición no tendría mucho sentido, puesto estarías comparando la dirección `0x05` con el código ASCII del caracter (lo que devuelva `frase[i]`). Así que lo mas lógico es que la condición **siempre** se cumpla.

A buena hora que el compilador mostró esa advertencia, de lo contrario, tendrías un tremendo [error lógico](https://techlib.net/definition/logic_error.html).

> > ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Lo que debes hacer es comparar enteros con enteros:

```c
if (frase[i] != ' ')
```

De esta manera, el compilador no lanza ninguna advertencia y esto se debe porque los tipos son compatibles (tanto `frase[i]` como `' '` son de tipo `char`). ¡Estás comparando enteros!